# Identify Certain Text Within Input Text Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text, input

Ok, hi there. Just have a quick question to ask. In basic terms, I'm trying to develop a TextEditor in Flash and Actionscript and What I'm trying to do for example is identify whether `"addEventListener"`
has been typed into my input field. From there I want to change the colour of the area that says `"addEventListener"` to say for example, blue.

So I was just wondering what is the most basic way to do this

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find all the instances of the word, then set a text format for them. Something like this: (assumes your text input is called `txt`)

```
//create a default format that you reset the whole text field to every time you check
var defaultTf:TextFormat = txt.defaultTextFormat;

function highlightWord(word:String, caseSensitive:Boolean = false){ 
  //the current text of the input text field
  var textBlock:String = txt.text;

  //lower case everything if you don't want case sensitivity
  if(!caseSensitive){             
    word = word.toLocaleLowerCase();        
    textBlock = textBlock.toLocaleLowerCase();   
  }    

  //an array to store all the starting indexes of the word
  var arr:Array = new Array();

  //helper vars for the loop below       
  var curIndex:int = 0;    
  var foundIndex:int;

  //loop so long as the word is found (the found index is 0 or greater)
  while(foundIndex > -1){
      foundIndex = textBlock.indexOf(word, curIndex);

      if(foundIndex > -1){
          //add the index of the found word to the array
          arr.push(foundIndex);

          //increment the index by word length
          curIndex = foundIndex + word.length;
      }
  }

  //create a text format to use to highlight the words (blue)
  var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(null,null,0x0000FF);

  //set everything to the default style
  txt.setTextFormat(defaultTf);

  //loop through the array of words, and highlight them with the text format
  for(var i:int=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      txt.setTextFormat(tf, arr[i],arr[i] + word.length);
  }
}

highlightWord("addEventListener");
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* get both the matches and the positions using the RegExp class:

```
    // change wholeText to a class variable or function param
    var wholeText:String = "...addEventListener( Event...";
    var pattern:RegExp = /addEventListener/g; 
    var result:Array = pattern.exec( wholeText ); 

    while ( result != null ) 
    { 
        trace( result.index, pattern.lastIndex, result ); 
        result = pattern.exec( wholeText ); 
    }
```

...to include the formatting, you would...

```
    var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat( null, null, 0x0000ff );
    var wholeText:String = "...addEventListener( Event...";
    var pattern:RegExp = /addEventListener/g; 
    var result:Array = pattern.exec( wholeText ); 

    while ( result != null ) 
    { 
        wholeText.setTextFormat( tf, result.index, pattern.lastIndex );
        result = pattern.exec( wholeText ); 
    }
```

I haven't performance checked this against BadFeelingAboutThis's method.  I provide it as a more compact possible solution.

Of course, you could functionize it easily, changing

```
    var pattern:RegExp = /addEventListener/g;
```

...to...

```
    function colorizeString( findMe:String ) : void
    {
        // ....
        var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp( findMe, "g" );
        // ...
    }
```

I've left it as case-sensitive.  If you wanted it to be case-insensitive, you'd change "g" to "gi".